# How to check child child component's type

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a component which takes as children other components and passes to them additional props.
Inside the `render` method of my component I have code like this

```
React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
  if (child.type === DataTableHeader)) {
    header = React.cloneElement(child, {
      filter, onFilterChange,
      sort, onSortChange
    })
  }
})
```

where `DataTableHeader` is another component.

The problem is that `child.type` is never equal to `DataTableHeader`.

In chrome debugger I see that `child.type` reference `DataTableHeader` from here

```
(function(factory,instantiate
/**/) {
return function DataTableHeader() {
         return instantiate(factory, this, arguments);
      }
})
```

whereas `DataTableHeader` points to my component.

The render method comes from `DataTable` component, and I use it like this:

```
<DataTable
  onFetchData={onFetchData}>
  <DataTableHeader>
    <DataTableHeaderCell sortField='name'>
      Name
    </DataTableHeaderCell>
  </DataTableHeader>
  {children}
</DataTable>
```

Comment: Can you provide the children list you're passing it? I know you've provided the Chrome Debugger, but can you show the JS that suggests it is being passed a child of type DataTableHeader?

Comment: Yes, I've updated question with the jsx where I use it.

Comment: But what are the actual children though?

Comment: In my case `children` is an array of `DataTableRow`, but it's not important here. In my example I pass `DataTableHeader` as a first child, and I would like to recognize this child in the `render` method of `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by `react-hot-loader` https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/304
As a workaround I define static field on `DataTableHeader` and use it instead of comparing type `type`